# Getting error in WindowBuilder in Eclipse because digits are being shown in different language

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

WindowBuilder was not able to parse source  lblNewLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, ११));.

line: 29 Invalid digit (valid ones are 0..9)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification section [3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) says integer number literals must use the ASCII digits 0-9, other Unicode number characters are not acceptable.

So you must use '11' rather than the Devanagari digit one characters.

Alternatively the `Integer.parseInt` method does accept any Unicode number character so you can use:

```
Integer.parseInt("११")
```